# Output a table with name and average of scores

Tags: javascript

```
    var member1 = prompt("Bowler's Name", "Name");
var member1score1 = prompt("Score from game 1", "");
var member1score2 = prompt("Score from game 2", "");
var member1score3 = prompt("Score from game 3", "");
var memeber1avg = ((memberscore1 + member1score2 + member1score3) / 3);


var member2 = prompt("Bowler's Name", "Name");
var member2score1 = prompt("Score from game 1", "");
var member2score2 = prompt("Score from game 2", "");
var member2score3 = prompt("Score from game 3", "");
var memeber2avg = ((memberscore1 + member1score2 + member1score3) / 3);


var member3 = prompt("Bowler's Name", "Name");
var member3score1 = prompt("Score from game 1", "");
var member3score2 = prompt("Score from game 2", "");
var member3score3 = prompt("Score from game 3", "");
var memeber3avg = ((memberscore1 + member1score2 + member1score3) / 3);


var member4 = prompt("Bowler's Name", "Name");
var member4score1 = prompt("Score from game 1", "");
var member4score2 = prompt("Score from game 2", "");
var member4score3 = prompt("Score from game 3", "");
var memeber4avg = ((memberscore1 + member1score2 + member1score3) / 3);
```

Ok, so I'm new to js, and I knowwww this can be done way simpler with arrays... just don't know how. Also how do I write this to a table?

Comment: *Death by prompt* comes to mind. Or at least a maiming.

Comment: There's a lot of duplicate code.  You might want to think about how you could write a single function that calculates the average for a single member.  Then call that function 3 times.

Comment: You're seemingly mixing several concepts together (not sure where arrays fit in). Can you use an html form? Event handlers?

Comment: Looking at [this closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733435/bowling-average-in-js), I see that what you need is to take three scores in and average them, and do it serially per player four times. So you need to a function that accepts a Name argument, and three integers, and outputs table markup that contains a table header (`<th>`) row (`<tr>`) with column names (`Name`, `Average`) followed by a row (`<tr>`) with two table cells (`<td>`) containing first the player name sent to the function, and the average of the three scores. This should all be in a `<table>` element.

Comment: So first you need a `function writePlayer(name, scores)` defined. `scores` is an array of scores.

Comment: Then, you need a loop to add `scores[i] + totalscore`.

Comment: Then you need to average the scores (`totalscore / scores.length`).

Comment: Then return (or `document.write(table)`, depending) a `table` that, in plaintext, represents a `<table><tr><th></th></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>` with the JS `name` and calculated `avgscore` interpolated (`'<td>'+name+'</td>'`).

Comment: Then you need to call your `writePlayer('Max',[123,135,149])` function four times.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an object for the member, and give it methods for input and average calcuation:

```
function Member() {
  this.score = [];
  this.name = prompt("Bowler's Name", "Name");
}

Member.prototype = {

  inputScore: function(cnt){
    for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
      this.score[i] = parseInt(prompt('Score from game ' + (i + 1), ''), 10);
    }
  },

  getAverage: function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.score.length; i++) {
      sum += this.score[i];
    }
    return sum / this.score.length;
  }

};

// create four members and input data
var members = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  members[i] = new Member();
  members[i].inputScore(3);
}

// output averages    
for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
  alert('Average for ' + members[i].name + ' is ' + members[i].getAverage());
}
```

Comment: It makes more sense if you read the "other" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733435/bowling-average-in-js

Comment: I like it, but *way* over the OP. An easy A++ if the prof doesn't get suspicious.

Comment: Might want to specify a radix of 10 for the `parseInt` function.

Comment: @Russell Dias: Yes, that's right. Fixed that. People normally don't expect to be able to input numbers in octal. :)